# How to fail base clause and use recursion prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to make sure every member in the list is between 0 and 25, I wrote the following code:

I tried using cut,failure and even cut with failure.

```
test25([]).
    test25([H|T]):-
        H>=0,H=<25,test25(T).
```

I get true when the elements are under 25 but I also get true if the base clause which is an empty list.
Expected result:

```
    test25([]).
false;
test25([1,2,3]).
true;
test25([1,2,33]).
false;
```

Comment: Change your base case to `test25([H]) :- H >= 0, H =< 25.` :)

Comment: Thank you for the help!